# File does not close in Word 10 or takes VERY long

Tags: microsoft-word

My Word 10 was working fine. Since about two weeks, when I try to close file (Using File/Close), it hangs up.
Anybody can help me with that.

Comment: The problem could be Word, the file, a hardware problem, programs you have running in the background, etc.  Please provide details of your hardware (computer model and resources), Windows version, any changes that may have been made to your system around the time the problem started, what you have running in the background, the extent of any symptoms (one file, all files, files other than Word, any other problems), what happens when it hangs (just takes a long time to close but you can do other things vs. the entire computer freezes)?

Comment: I found the problem and the fixer. The problem was in MS word. The cause was add-inns that I installed. I removed the add-ins (the process is File/word options/add-in/manage [COM Add-Ins], press go. Then uncheck the boxes beside the add-in causing the problem).

Comment: Can you post that as an answer?  That will make this more helpful to others who may encounter a similar problem.  Thanks.